# How to commit programmatically via a managed bean?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a managed bean that changes an attribute value and calls a popup.
I need also to commit the changes made (without having to click a commit button), I tried some code but it does nothing.
Help me, please.

```
DCBindingContainer bindings = (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("Commit");
operationBinding.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following functions to commit the change made to an Iterator programmatically (In an action listener for example) :

```java
public static ViewObjectImpl getViewObjectFromIterator(String nomIterator) {
    ViewObjectImpl returnVO = null;
    DCBindingContainer dcb = (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    if (dcb != null) {
        DCIteratorBinding iter = dcb.findIteratorBinding(nomIterator);
        if (iter != null) {
            returnVO = (ViewObjectImpl)iter.getViewObject();
        }
    }
    return returnVO;
}

private void commit(String IteratorName) {
    ViewObject vo = this.getViewObjectFromIterator(IteratorName);
    try {
        vo.getApplicationModule().getTransaction().validate();
        vo.getApplicationModule().getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        String validationErrorMessage = e.getDetailMessage();
        //Occur when some committed data is rejected due to validation error.
        //log it : log(Level.WARNING, " " + validationErrorMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //Log it and warn something unexpected occured
    }


}

//In your action listener simply call the commit function as follow
//You can Find YOUR_ITERATOR_NAME the your PageDef Binding file in the Executables Column
commit("YOUR_ITERATOR_NAME");
```

See more : https://gist.github.com/CedricL46/04570c1f078583321ad680ee8ba28f72

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried what you suggested, but still nothing. The commit function is called without errors but the changes made are not committed.

Comment: What kind of component is getting the change ? If this is an inputText and you want to notify your View Object that the value changed without clicking a commit button you also need to set the AutoSubmit attribute to true

Comment: yes, it's an input text and i  did set the AutoSubmit  attribute to true.

Comment: so , we're getting somewhere i just added the commit function before calling the pop up. it works only if i click on the button twice. does it make any sence? here's the code:        lu.setSubmittedValue("1");
       AdfFacesContext ctx = AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
       ctx.addPartialTarget(lu);
      this.commitIterator("SsMailVO2Iterator");
          RichPopup.PopupHints hints = new RichPopup.PopupHints();
          this.getPopUp().show(hints);

Comment: To avoid the first validation step you could set the immediate attribute to True as well. It will bypass the validation stage and call directly your listener. Autosubmit + immediat may do the trick. Can't do more without knowing what popup you're mentionning :)